# ArcMap cannot connect to the previous versions of license manager after Windows update

Tags: arcgis-desktop, windows-10, arcgis-license-manager

[image: error while opening ArcMap]

I have updated the Windows to Windows 10 Pro, and since then I am unable to open ArcMap 10.5.1. Upon clicking the ArcMap icon the window appears with an error message.

Check the attached image for the error.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Please always provide errors as formatted text rather than only as a picture.

Comment: Did you check the suggestion in the error message? Is the license manager version 10.5 or newer?

Comment: @Berend the error gave a suggestion to contact the organization's lisence administrator or ensure that license manager is version 10.5 or newer.

Comment: @Sohaib And what was the administrator's response?

Comment: @Berend no, I have not contacted him. It is possible only tomorrow.

Comment: If you open the ArcGIS License Server Administrator do you see that your licenses are available?  You can stop and start the license service and see if that helps. There is a diagnostics option.

Comment: @johns I am unable to see the licenses in the ArcGIS administrator. Please explain second sentence in detail.

Comment: @johns it shows under the heading of License manager env. variable info. 
ARCGIS_LICENSE_FILE:N/A
LM_LICENSE_FILE:N/A

Comment: @Sohaib The ArcGIS administrator is different from the License Server Administrator.  Both have start shortcuts within ArcGIS  on the start menu.

Comment: The License Manager usually requires advanced Windows (admin) privileges most of us do not have. The Administrator does not. Its first line should list the License Manager version and install date. But an admin would need to look at whether it is running OK.